# Getting True/False values from Firebase if a tree/value exists. Cannot get this to work

Tags: javascript, variables, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

Been at this all day. I am building a social network.
It checks to see if two users have connected to each other, if they have a structure like this is created.
ROOT->Groups->RequestingUser->UserTheyWant

When two people have each requested each other, I want two variables to compare so if both are true I can continue. I can not get this to work.

I have tried so many iterations of this but I cannot get true/false values from this, I don't want to post all my attempts... Hopefully this gets it across.

I just need the two functions didYouRequest and didTheyRequest to return true/false OR didTheVisitorConnect / checkIfOtherProfilePersonConnected actually set outside the damn function so i can compare them.

```
$scope.connect = () => {
        // my userid -> and set key in there for who they want to visit
        console.log('added ' + $scope.profile.name + ' as friend.');
        return fbGroupsDb.child(userLoggedIn).child(userUID).set(
        {
            connected: true
        }); 
   };


var didTheVisitorConnect = false;
$scope.didTheVisitorConnect = false;

var checkIfOtherProfilePersonConnected = false;
$scope.checkIfOtherProfileConnected = false;


   var didYouRequest = fbGroupsDb.child(userLoggedIn).child(userUID).once('value').then( function (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
            $scope.didTheVisitorConnect = true;
            didTheVisitorConnect = true;
            console.log('Did You Request? : ', didTheVisitorConnect);
            return true;
        } else {
            $scope.didTheVisitorConnect = false;
            didTheVisitorConnect = false;
            console.log('Did You Request? : ', didTheVisitorConnect);
            return false; 
        }
    });


    var didTheyRequest = fbGroupsDb.child(userUID).child(userLoggedIn).once('value').then( function (snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
                $scope.checkIfOtherProfileConnected = true;
                checkIfOtherProfilePersonConnected = true;
                console.log('Have they requested You? : ', checkIfOtherProfilePersonConnected);
                return true;
            } else {
                $scope.checkIfOtherProfileConnected = false;
                checkIfOtherProfilePersonConnected = false;
                console.log('Have they requested You? : ', checkIfOtherProfilePersonConnected);
                return false;
            }
    });
```

Comment: `didYouRequest` and `didTheyRequest` are not functions, they're promises for boolean values. Just wait for both of them using `Promise.all` and do your comparison when the values are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
Promise.all([didYouRequest, didTheyRequest]).then(function([you, they]) {
    if (you && they) {
        …
    } else {
        …
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what I needed. Spent about 5 hours on this and was going in the wrong directly completely :)